# I need help to overwrite images on html page upon clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have stored my images in an array called arr
I have put a button on the html page called 'Next' so that  whenever the user clicks the next button,the next image is picked up and overwrites the previous one
the issue is the image on html page does not get overwritten by the next image( stored in the array),so how do I accomplish this

please help me as I am new to javascipt.

```
<body>
    <script>
        var arr = ["apple.jpg","kiwi.jpg", "pineapple.jpg","mango.jpg"];

        function a()
        {
            
            image5 = document.getElementById("image5");
            console.log(arr[0]);
            image5=new Image();
            image5.src = arr[0];
                 console.log("file is " + image5.src);
            arr.splice(0,1);
        }
    </script>
    <img src="apple.jpg" id="image5" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    <button onClick="a();">Next</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Why did you add this line: `image5=new Image();` ? You want to change what `#image5` shows, but you then overwrite the reference to that element (stored in `image5`) with something new (`new Image()`) and change the `.src` property of that new object.

Comment: Sorry my typo ; now i removed it. i can see the file path being created in console log but image on html page is not getting overwritten.pls help me

Comment: Just remove the line with that `new Image()` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pretty much just cleaned up the code and had a variable that is the indicator to which picture comes up on the array and its loops. Also, I made the script tag defer so the tag loads after the whole page is so the function runs

```
<body>
    <script defer>
        var arr = ["apple.jpg","kiwi.jpg", "pineapple.jpg","mango.jpg"];
        var image5 = document.getElementById("image5");
        var i = 0;
        function a(){
            if(i>=4){i=0;}
            image5.src = arr[i];
            console.log("file is " + image5.src);
            i++;
        }
    </script>
    <img src="apple.jpg" id="image5" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    <button onclick="a()">Next</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks (and also for the script defer tag insight)